# datetime to Unix timestamp with millisecond precision

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to do something really simple, convert a `datetime` object three days into the future into a Unix UTC timestamp:

```
import datetime, time
then = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=3)
# Method 1
print then.strftime("%s")
# Method 2
print time.mktime(then.timetuple())
# Method 3 
print time.mktime(then.timetuple()) * 1000
```

Method 1 and 2 give me Unix time in *seconds*, not milliseconds, and method 3 gives me milliseconds with no actual millisecond precision.

When I simply print `then`, I get `datetime.datetime(2011, 11, 19, 15, 16, 8, 278271)`, so I know that the precision is available for milliseconds. How can I get a Unix timestamp with actual millisecond precision? If it's returned as a float and I have to flatten it to an an `int`, that's fine. Is there a solution I'm looking for that does this?

Comment: related: [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8777753/4279)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Datetime objects have a field named `microsecond`. So one way to achieve what you need is:

```
time.mktime(then.timetuple())*1e3 + then.microsecond/1e3
```

This returns milliseconds since UNIX epoch with the required precision.

Comment: You're missing the punchline: `print time.mktime(then.timetuple()) * 1000 + then.microsecond/1000`

Comment: Nice solution, especially the ultra-hacker saving of one character by using `1e3` instead of `1000`.

Comment: Naftuli, not really since 1e3 involves 3 distinct characters (1,e,3), and 1000 uses only 2 (1 and 0)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but microseconds are millions of a second not thousandths. Also, I don't know why you multiply then divide. `time.mktime(then.timetuple()) + then.microsecond/1e6` works for me.

Comment: @TheHerk I am not sure, but I think he wants the result in milliseconds. Your solution gives seconds, with milliseconds as decimal places.

Comment: @jfs is right, use `timestamp = dt.timestamp()` instead.

Answer (score 27):

In Python 3.3 and above, which support the [`datetime.timestamp()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) method, you can do this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

(datetime.now(timezone.utc) + timedelta(days=3)).timestamp() * 1e3
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: My measurement shows that using timestamp() is also a lot faster than the solution by Adam Zalcman.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming someone is interested in UTC, the following in valid after Python 3.3:

```
from datetime import datetime

now = int(datetime.utcnow().timestamp()*1e3)
```

Python 3.3 [release notes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#datetime):

> New `datetime.datetime.timestamp()` method: Return POSIX timestamp corresponding to the `datetime` instance.

Intermediate results:

```
In [1]: datetime.utcnow().timestamp()
Out[1]: 1582562542.407362

In [2]: datetime.utcnow().timestamp()*1e3
Out[2]: 1582562566701.329

In [3]: int(datetime.utcnow().timestamp()*1e3)
Out[3]: 1582562577296
```

Comment: Be aware: This is only correct when the local timezone is UTC. `datetime.utcnow()` returns a naive timestamp (!). When calling method `.timestamp()` on it, it is assumed to be local timezone - which gives the wrong POSIX timestamp.

Comment: Thanks @HåkonT.! I will link the explanation coming from this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573873/python-datetime-utcnow-returning-incorrect-datetime

Answer (score 4):

```
long((time.time() + 0.5) * 1000)
```

this has millisecond precision

Comment: what it I have to get timestamp upto 7 decimal places something like this:1469172167.3014405

Answer (score 4):

Day is always `86400` seconds in POSIX time. To get POSIX timestamp 3 days into the future as a float (with fraction of a second):

```
import time

DAY = 86400 # seconds
future = time.time() + 3 * DAY
```

It assumes that `time.gmtime(0)` is 1970 (POSIX Epoch).

If you already have a naive datetime object that represents time in the local timezone then the timestamp may be ambiguous during DST transitions. To avoid ambiguity, you could use a timezone aware datetime object or a naive datetime object that represents time in UTC.

To convert a local datetime `dt` to seconds since the Epoch:

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime

timestamp = dt.timestamp() # Python 3.3+
timestamp = mktime(dt.timetuple()) + dt.microsecond / 1e6 # Python 2.7
```

It may fail if the local timezone had different utc offset in the past and the `time` implementation has no access to timezone database on the system. Use `pytz` to handle such cases.

To convert UTC datetime `utc_dt` to POSIX timestamp:

```
timestamp = (utc_dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
```

To get milliseconds, just multiply any of the float number of seconds by 1e3.

Comment: Thanks! Note, should be `dt.microsecond`, not `dt.microseconds`

Answer (score 2):

If sticking with datetimes in UTC, you can keep with that abstraction and leverage timedelta:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

epoch = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)

def dt_from_ms(ms):
    return datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ms / 1000.0)

def dt_to_ms(dt):
    delta = dt - epoch
    return int(delta.total_seconds() * 1000)
```

then:

```
now = datetime.utcnow()
now
-> datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 25, 1, 30, 42, 765846)  # note microsecond precision

dt_to_ms(now)
-> 1485307842765

dt_from_ms(1485307842765)
-> datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 25, 1, 30, 42, 765000)  # note millisecond precision

then = now + timedelta(days=3)
dt_to_ms(then)
-> 1485567042765

(1485567042765 - 1485307842765) / (24*60*60*1000.0)
-> 3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 2.7 or 3.2+, you can use [`timedelta.total_seconds()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) to get this fairly easily:

```
import datetime, time
print time.time() + datetime.timedelta(days=3).total_seconds()
```

Comment: [Day is always `86400` seconds in POSIX time.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22574765/4279)

Comment: Why time delta?