# Python datetime.utcnow() returning incorrect datetime

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, utc

```
datetime.utcnow()
```

This call is returning an incorrect datetime, delayed from UTC/GMT by 1 hour (check in: http://www.worldtimeserver.com/current_time_in_UTC.asp).

Is it working like it should be?

For example, it's returning, right now:

```
2015-02-17 23:58:44.761000.
```

Current UTC time is: 00:58, not 23:58

Comment: what's your timezone?

Comment: What does `time.timezone` say, and is it the right offset (in seconds) for your timezone?

Comment: It says 10800. What is right offset for my timezone?

Comment: what does `datetime.utcnow()` return right now? The local timezone does not matter.

Comment: It returns 2015-02-17 23:58:44.761000. Current UTC time is: 00:58, not 23:58.

Comment: make sure it is not ["Clock time is off on dual boot" issue](http://askubuntu.com/q/169376/3712)

Comment: I checked right now, it's not this issue. I'm using Windows 7 and the registry values merging doesn't fixed this incorrect utcnow().

Comment: Are the values returned by `time.time()`, `time.gmtime()`, `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()` consistent with each other on your machine?

Comment: I faced similar issue on Google App Engine ( Python ) and raised a ticket https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12565

Answer (score 80):

I know I'm five years late, but I had the same problem tonight. In my experience, the solution to the problem was to use the aware UTC datetime:

```
utc_dt_aware = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
```

If you google "utcnow() wrong" this is the first result you get, so I thought it would be good to answer anyway.

Answer (score 15):

[`datetime.utcnow()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow) uses OS provided values.

[`datetime.utcnow()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow) uses [`gettimeofday(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html) or `time.time()` on Python 2 (and `gmtime(3)` to convert the result into broken-down time).

`time.time()` uses [`gettimeofday(2)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html), `ftime(3)`, `time(2)`. Newer CPython versions may use [`clock_gettime(2)`, `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27830403/4279).

You could check the self-consistency as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

print(datetime.utcnow())
print(datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=time.time()))
print(datetime(*time.gmtime()[:6]))
```

Here's (non-tested) code that calls `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()` on Windows [based on CPython source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/28bfbf91bb53/Python/pytime.c#l21):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import ctypes.wintypes
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def utcnow_microseconds():
    system_time = ctypes.wintypes.FILETIME()
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(ctypes.byref(system_time))
    large = (system_time.dwHighDateTime << 32) + system_time.dwLowDateTime
    return large // 10 - 11644473600000000

print(datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(microseconds=utcnow_microseconds()))
```

Here's code that calls [`clock_gettime()` on Python 2](https://gist.github.com/zed/5073409).

Answer (score -8):

Problem only occurs with utc time (Python3).

e.g. System time:

```
$ date

Wed Jul 15 10:44:26 BST 2015
```

Python time correct when using datetime.now():

```
>>> datetime.now()

datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 15, 10, 44, 30, 775840)
```

...But incorrect by one hour when using datetime.utcnow():

```
>>> datetime.utcnow()

datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 15, 9, 44, 32, 599823)
```

UTC's problem is it doesn't know my timezone.

You have to tell it, with the help of a timezone module called pytz:

```
>>> import pytz
>>> mytz = pytz.timezone('Europe/London')
>>> pytz.utc.localize(datetime.utcnow(), is_dst=None).astimezone(mytz)

datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 15, 11, 3, 43, 688681, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/London' BST+1:00:00 DST>)
```

References:

[pytz - Converting UTC and timezone to local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25264811/pytz-converting-utc-and-timezone-to-local-time)

https://opensourcehacker.com/2008/06/30/relativity-of-time-shortcomings-in-python-datetime-and-workaround/

http://sweemengs-tech-world.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/get-correct-datetime-value-for-python.html

http://bugs.python.org/issue5094)

Comment: why do you think that `utcnow()` is incorrect? Unless your local timezone has zero utc offset; utc time will be different from the local time. Unrelated: you could use `datetime.now(timezone)`, to get the current time in the given timezone. The references that you've provided are not good. For the first one; read my comments there.

Comment: It is unclear why you've provided the link to *"datetime lacks concrete tzinfo implementation for UTC"* Python issue (it is fixed in Python 3; It is easy to workaround in Python 2; It is not a concern at all if you are already using `pytz`).

Comment: My answer shows how utcnow() was incorrect. It was 1 hour off from my system time. I verified this by reading the clocks wot are on my wall. The links are merely those I used to find a solution. Other readers may find them useful/interesting. They might not meet yr high standards, J.F., but they gave me the information I needed to solve the problem and make Python3 give me a correct utc time. My post originally included a snarky comment about the Python bug not being fixed, as far as I was concerned, because I had to look up a fix and that fix was called pytz. But it has disappeared. Meh.

Comment: BST has nonzero utc offset therefore it is *expected* that `utcnow()` returns datetime that is different from `now()`: "local time = utc time + utc offset"

Comment: Ah yah. Hokay. Correct time, or "correct utc time" - depends on your perspective, and your time zone.

Comment: **wrong**. `utcnow()` is the same around the world (+/- clock sync.). It does not matter what is your local timezone; utc time remains the same e.g., it is now `2015-07-16T23:41:30Z` (UTC). If you run `datetime.utcnow()` on your computer then you should get similar time regardless of your timezone (if you are on a POSIX system; you could easily change your timezone using `TZ` envvar and see for yourself that `utcnow()` does not change (`now()` is likely to change if you change your local timezone). `.utcnow()` may jump by around 26 seconds if you use "right" timezone but it is another issue.

Comment: Okay already! Gotcha, like, yesterday.-). But your clarification is most well put, and most welcome. From the perspective of someone just trying to get an accurate datestamp, though, and making use of what *desperately-poorly documented* tools are available, utc is wrong and needs correcting. utc is inherently wrong and inherently in need of correction, depending on your perspective.

Comment: You have some incorrect preconceptions about utc. You should *prefer* working with utc in most cases (it is much easier than working with local time) e.g., [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26313848/4279). See, [Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2532962/4279).

Comment: From the perspective of a user who needs to archive a file for human consumption, with a date that records its correct local time of capture, utc is irrelevant, and actually a nuisance.

Comment: You seem to completely miss the point of using UTC. I'd go as far as to say you should *always* store UTC timestamps, and *then* convert them to local time when displaying to users (that's even what your workaround with pytz does). Saying "UTC is irrelevant, and actually a nuisance" just shows your inexperience in dealing with datetimes. I'm utterly confused how you don't seem to get the benefits of the universal nature of UTC.

Answer (score -8):

I know I am tremendously late in replying to this.

I have tried doing this recently and therefore I suggest using **`datetime.now()`** instead of **`datetime.utcnow()`**. For my simple application that works fine.

Comment: As the name suggests, utcnow() and now() are not the same thing. datetime.now() returns the local date.