# Python resolution of datetime.now()

Tags: python, windows, datetime, python-3.4

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
for i in range(1000):
    curr_time  = datetime.now()
    print(curr_time)
    time.sleep(0.0001)
```

I was testing the resolution of `datetime.now()`. Since it supposes to output in microsecond, I expected that each print will be different.

However, I always get something like that.

```
...
2015-07-10 22:38:47.212073
2015-07-10 22:38:47.212073
2015-07-10 22:38:47.212073
2015-07-10 22:38:47.212073
2015-07-10 22:38:47.212073
2015-07-10 22:38:47.212073
2015-07-10 22:38:47.212073
2015-07-10 22:38:47.212073
2015-07-10 22:38:47.212073
2015-07-10 22:38:47.212073
2015-07-10 22:38:47.212073
2015-07-10 22:38:47.212073
2015-07-10 22:38:47.212073
2015-07-10 22:38:47.213074
2015-07-10 22:38:47.213074
2015-07-10 22:38:47.213074
2015-07-10 22:38:47.213074
2015-07-10 22:38:47.213074
2015-07-10 22:38:47.213074
2015-07-10 22:38:47.213074
2015-07-10 22:38:47.213074
2015-07-10 22:38:47.213074
2015-07-10 22:38:47.213074
2015-07-10 22:38:47.213074
...
```

Why does that happen? Is there any way that I can get an accurate timestamp down to the microsecond? Actually I don't need microseconds, but it would be nice to get 0.1ms resolution.

=== UPDATE ====

I compared it with using time.perf_counter() and adding to the starting `datetime`
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    import time

```
datetime0 = datetime.now()
t0 = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(1000):
    print('datetime.now(): ', datetime.now())
    print('time.perf_counter(): ', datetime0 + timedelta(0, time.perf_counter()-t0))
    print('\n')

    time.sleep(0.000001)
```

I am not sure how 'accurate' it really is, but the resolution is at least higher.... it doesn't seems to matter as my computer cannot even print at a speed that high. For my purpose, which I simply need different timestamps to distinguish different entries, this is good enough for me.

```
...
datetime.now():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.010377
time.perf_counter():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.010352


datetime.now():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.010377
time.perf_counter():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.010545


datetime.now():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.010377
time.perf_counter():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.010745


datetime.now():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.011377
time.perf_counter():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.010961


datetime.now():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.011377
time.perf_counter():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.011155


datetime.now():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.011377
time.perf_counter():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.011369


datetime.now():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.011377
time.perf_counter():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.011596


datetime.now():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.012379
time.perf_counter():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.011829


datetime.now():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.012379
time.perf_counter():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.012026


datetime.now():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.012379
time.perf_counter():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.012232


datetime.now():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.012379
time.perf_counter():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.012424


datetime.now():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.012379
time.perf_counter():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.012619


datetime.now():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.013380
time.perf_counter():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.012844


datetime.now():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.013380
time.perf_counter():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.013044


datetime.now():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.013380
time.perf_counter():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.013242


datetime.now():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.013380
time.perf_counter():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.013437


datetime.now():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.013380
time.perf_counter():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.013638


datetime.now():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.014379
time.perf_counter():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.013903


datetime.now():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.014379
time.perf_counter():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.014125


datetime.now():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.014379
time.perf_counter():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.014328


datetime.now():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.014379
time.perf_counter():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.014526


datetime.now():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.014379
time.perf_counter():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.014721


datetime.now():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.015381
time.perf_counter():  2015-07-10 23:24:18.014919

...
```

Comment: I'm sure it depends on the OS clock, and OS clocks typically aren't that precise.

Comment: The maximum resolution of your time stamp will depend on what is the maximum resolution of your time source.

Comment: I see. I am using Windows 8. It seems to have a resolution of 1ms. I guess there's no way to exceed that given the OS?

Comment: What happens if you [run `datetime.utcnow()` or `utcnow_microseconds()` that call `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()` in a loop (remove `time.sleep()`)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28574340/4279)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a limitation of `time.sleep` on your system, rather than `datetime.now()`... or possibly both. **What OS and what version and distribution of Python are you running on?**

Your system may not offer the "subsecond precision" mentioned in the `time.sleep` docs:

```
sleep(...)
    sleep(seconds)

    Delay execution for a given number of seconds.  The argument may be
    a floating point number for subsecond precision.
```

On **Linux 3.x on amd64 with CPython 2.7**, I get something pretty close to the 0.0001 time steps that you intended:

```
2015-07-10 19:58:24.353711
2015-07-10 19:58:24.353879
2015-07-10 19:58:24.354052
2015-07-10 19:58:24.354227
2015-07-10 19:58:24.354401
2015-07-10 19:58:24.354577
2015-07-10 19:58:24.354757
2015-07-10 19:58:24.354938
```

Comment: I am using Windows 8 with Python 34. I think it's the problem with datetime.now(). I tried time.clock(). it seems to show a different time every loop. Probably I need to convert the value I get from time.clock() to a datetime.

Comment: Good to know. I suggest [filing a bug report](//bugs.python.org) if there isn't one already!

Comment: @tuzzer: `datetime.now()` has microsecond **precision** ([it might  support nanoseconds in the future](https://bugs.python.org/issue15443)) -- check `.resolution` attribute. It says *nothing* about **accuracy** that is probably ~10ms to 55ms (ms==milliseconds) on Windows ([`.utcnow()` uses `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()` on modern CPython and Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28574340/4279)). See [Precision is not the same as accuracy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/09/02/459952.aspx)