# How was datetime.utcnow() changed between Python 2 and Python 3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, python-3.x

I'm fiddling around with Python's [datetime.datetime.utcnow()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow) function in both Python 2.7.6 and 3.4.3 and I noticed something interesting: the microsecond value in Python27 is always 000.

I'm on a Windows 7 Professional (64bit) machine. My Python27 install is 32bit, and my Python34 install is 64bit.

#### In Python 2, microseconds are always 000:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 20, 23, 7, 27, 55000)
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 20, 23, 7, 27, 991000)
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 20, 23, 7, 28, 279000)
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 20, 23, 7, 29, 7000)
```

#### In Python 3, the microsecond value is more reasonable:

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 20, 23, 8, 32, 97893)
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 20, 23, 8, 32, 665950)
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2015, 7, 20, 23, 8, 33, 322016)
```

**Could anyone provide me with info on what was changed between 2 and 3 or why this is happening?** I haven't been able to find anything in the docs, and I have no idea where to start looking in the python source.

In addition, how can I get microsecond datetime accuracy in Python2? I'm hesitant to use [time.time()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/time.html#time.time) because of the warning in the docs regarding the system clock being rolled back. Since I'm only interested in deltas, I should be able to use [time.clock()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/time.html#time.clock), correct?

Comment: Looks like it only had millisecond precision in Python 2, boosted to microsecond precision in 3. Are you restricted to Python 2 for your project?

Comment: All of the docs say that Python2 has microsecond resolution for timedelta objects. Not limited to Py2, just curious on the details on the change.

Comment: The Python 2 behaviour doesn't seem to occur on Mac OS X.

Comment: related: [Python datetime.utcnow() returning incorrect datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28574340/4279)

Comment: if the system clock is rolled back then obviously `utcnow()` as well as `time.time()` will reflect that (they use the same OS-provided functions underneath)

Comment: See Python issues: (for Python 3.3+) [Use GetSystemTimeAsFileTime() to get a resolution of 100 ns on Windows](http://bugs.python.org/issue13845) and (for Python 3.5+) [precise time.time() under Windows 8: use GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTim](http://bugs.python.org/issue19007)

Comment: Thanks @j-f-sebastian, I didn't know that. I also just saw the Python3.3 deprecation warning for `time.clock()` so I guess I'll just have to use `time.time()` and hope no one is messing with the system clock :-P. Also, nice finds on the issues - that's the kind of info I was looking for.

Comment: @dthor: what function to use depends on your use-case. Read the docs for `time.monotonic()`, `time.perf_counter()`, `time.process_time()` and see whatever one suits you best.