# time.time() drift over repeated calls

Tags: python, macos, time, signal-processing, clock

I am getting a timestamp every time a key is pressed like this:

```
init_timestamp = time.time()
while (True):
    c = getch()
    offset = time.time() - init_timestamp
    print("%s,%s" % (c,offset), file=f)
```

([`getch` from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/510364/3707400)).

I am verifying the timestamps against an audio recording of me actually typing the keys. After lining the first timestamp up with the waveform, subsequent timestamps drift slighty but consistently. By this I mean that the saved timestamps are later than the keypress waveforms and get later and later as time goes on.

I am reasonably sure the waveform timing is correct (i.e. the recording is not fast or slow), because in the recording I also included the ticking of a very accurate clock which lines up perfectly with the second markers.

I am aware that there are unavoidable limits to the accuracy of `time.time()`, but this does not seem to account for what I'm seeing - if it was equally wrong on both sides that would be acceptable, but I do not want it to gradually diverge more and more from the truth.

Why would I be seeing this drifting behaviour and what can I do to avoid it?

Comment: Have you tried `time.clock()`, on some systems, this is more accurate then `time.time()`

Comment: @muddyfish no, `time.clock()` would definitely be the wrong thing to use here. `time.clock()` is processor clock time (it won't advance if the program doesn't use any clock cycles), instead of wall clock time (`time.time()`). See also: http://pymotw.com/2/time/

Comment: Ah, correction: On Windows `time.clock()` does in fact seem to be returning wall-clock seconds. *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

Just solved this by using `time.monotonic()` instead of `time.time()`. `time.time()` seems to use `gettimeofday` ([at least here it does](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/master/Modules/timemodule.c#L871)) which is apparently really bad for measuring walltime differences because of NTP syncing issues:

> gettimeofday() and time() should only be used to get the current time if the current wall-clock time is actually what you want. They should never be used to measure time or schedule an event X time into the future.
>
> You usually aren't running NTP on your wristwatch, so it probably won't jump a second or two (or 15 minutes) in a random direction because it happened to sync up against a proper clock at that point. Good NTP implementations try to not make the time jump like this. **They instead make the clock go faster or slower so that it will drift to the correct time**. But while it's drifting you either have a clock that's going too fast or too slow. It's not measuring the passage of time properly.

([link](https://blog.habets.se/2010/09/gettimeofday-should-never-be-used-to-measure-time)). So basically measuring differences between `time.time()` calls is a bad idea.

Comment: the current cpython may use [`clock_gettime(2)`, `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28574340/4279). Have you checked that `time.time()` drifts while `time.monotonic()` is accurate enough in your case? What is your OS, python version?

Comment: OSX, python 3.4.1. I am not getting any noticeable drift with `time.monotonic`, and `time.time` was definitely drifting.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which OS you are using you will either need to use `time.time()` or `time.clock()`.

For windows OS's you will need to use `time.clock` this give you will clock seconds as a float. `time.time()` on windows if I remember correctly `time.time()` is only accurate within 16ms.

For posix systems (linux, osx) you should be using `time.time()` this is a float which returns the number of seconds since the epoch.

In your code add the following to make your application a little more cross system compatible.

```
import os
if os.name == 'posix':
    from time import time as get_time
else:
    from time import clock as get_time

# now use get_time() to return the timestamp
init_timestamp = get_time()
while (True):
    c = getch()
    offset = get_time() - init_timestamp
    print("%s,%s" % (c,offset), file=f)
    ...
```

Comment: you probably want `timeit.default_timer()`