# Why would Python's datetime.utcnow() always return the same value for microseconds?

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x, python-3.4, python-datetime

I'm playing around with Python's datetime.datetime.utcnow() method and I'm noticing that the microsecond value is always the same.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 16, 23, 20, 46, 42286)
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 16, 23, 20, 55, 505286)
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 16, 23, 21, 1, 552286)
```

Notice how the microsecond value is always 286. Why would that be? And what can I do to fix that?

A little more info: `time.time()` also always has 286us. The millisecond values are fine. I think that this is actually the root cause, since I believe that datetime.datetime.utcnow() calls time.time().

---

Here's a short script that shows that it's not just luck:

```
import datetime, random, time

for wait_time in [random.random() for _ in range(10)]:
    time.sleep(wait_time)
    print("Waited {}, result {}".format(wait_time, datetime.datetime.utcnow()))
```

Result:

```
Waited 0.6074311218736113, result 2015-11-16 23:35:24.603286
Waited 0.960317012489652, result 2015-11-16 23:35:25.563286
Waited 0.13555474339177553, result 2015-11-16 23:35:25.698286
Waited 0.6179213307667111, result 2015-11-16 23:35:26.315286
Waited 0.2872301475401443, result 2015-11-16 23:35:26.602286
Waited 0.42578113509089066, result 2015-11-16 23:35:27.027286
Waited 0.647233264729425, result 2015-11-16 23:35:27.674286
Waited 0.38930513172405146, result 2015-11-16 23:35:28.063286
Waited 0.6500370260649043, result 2015-11-16 23:35:28.713286
Waited 0.9807308512288959, result 2015-11-16 23:35:29.693286
```

Thanks,

---

#### System Info:

- Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
- Windows 7 Professional, Service Pack 1. 64 bit.
- Intel Core i5-2400 @ 3.10GHz

#### Results from time.get_clock_info()

```
Name          Adjustable  Implementation             Monotonic  Resolution (seconds)
============  ==========  =========================  =========  ====================
clock         False       QueryPerformanceCounter()  True       3.3106597e-07
monotomic     False       GetTickCount64()           True       0.015600099999
perf_counter  False       QueryPerformanceCounter()  True       3.3106597e-07
process_time  False       GetProcessTime()           True       1e-7
time          True        GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()  False      0.015600099999
```

---

### Final Edit:

So, I come back to this the next morning (computer stayed on all night) and I started up the python interpreter again and everything is fine now!

What the heck, man?

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 17, 17, 19, 17, 626982)
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 17, 17, 19, 18, 234043)
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 17, 17, 19, 19, 106130)
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2015, 11, 17, 17, 20, 7, 707990)
```

I'm still interested in why this would/could have happened in the first place, so if anyone has any additional information that would be great. Sadly I don't know if I'll be able to replicate it...

Comment: Good timing? I can't replicate that.

Comment: It looks different on each call to me.

`datetime.datetime(year, month, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[, tzinfo]]]]])`. The year, month, day, and hour are the same.

I'm going to guess that your system clock just doesn't output that precision... we're talking about nanoseconds, not microseconds.

Comment: It's quite possible that the system clock on your computer does not have the necessary precision to handle that those digits of microsecond. I'm not sure why it would not be 000 as the final 3 digits though.

Comment: Nope, waiting by random amounts always results in the same 286us value. Plus the odds of it happening 30x in a row is infinitesimally small. I only happened to show 3 of them in the original post.

Comment: Your question title is about microseconds, but your concern is nanoseconds, which is what confused me originally. I'm with @dthor on this.

Comment: @HarryHarrison That's kind of what I figured, but I get reasonable microsecond accuracy when using time.perf_counter()

Comment: What's your processor?

Comment: @FBidu Intel Core i5-2400 @ 3.10GHz

Comment: That's very interesting, I can't replicate it either

Comment: Can anybody replicate what *I'm* seeing?

Comment: related: here's [how `datetime.utcnow()` is defined in terms of `GetSystemTimeAsFileTime()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28574340/4279) (on Windows 8+, you could try `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime()` instead -- it is also inaccurate but it has better resolution)

Comment: Run my code again, see what you get this time.

Answer (score 3):

There's an old joke about two people at a natural history museum wondering how old a dinosaur fossil is. A guard overhears them and says, "Oh, it's five-hundred million and seven years old". One of the people says, "that's an astonshing number, how was it determined?" The guard says, "Well, I was told it was five-hundred million years old during my orientation, and that was seven years ago."

This is the result of adding together two times with differing levels of precision. Say I start a clock at 12:03:06 and that clock only has minute resolution. If I add the time on my clock to the start time, I'll get a series of times like 12:03:06, 12:04:06, 12:05:06, and so on.

Windows is adding the time from a monotonic clock with millisecond resolution and an arbitrary start time to the time at which that clock read zero with microsecond resolution.

A common technique is simply to round the time to the resolution you are relying on, which of course must not be higher than the clock's guaranteed resolution. I believe the guaranteed resolution for this clock is 10 milliseconds.

Comment: Is this true for all windows versions? How are you explaning my results then?

Comment: I suspect for some reason, his TSC is unusable. Perhaps his CPU doesn't have a constant TSC frequency. I'm not certain. (The docs for the i5-2400 say it does. Maybe broken BIOS? Maybe weird power management settings? HPET disabled? HPET not set to 64-bit mode in the BIOS?)

Comment: It's a completely different chip. Do you have a consistent delta?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I understand what you're saying in the 2nd paragraph, but my question then becomes: how is it that I'm *always* starting my 1ms clock on 286us? Using your example, I'd expect the next time I start the clock to be 12:08:27, 12:09:27, 12:10:27, etc.

Comment: @dthor The clock started when the system started.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: this is not an answer.

---

I saw completely different microseconds, so I made this experiment:

```
ms = 0
for _ in range(10000):
    ms_ = datetime.datetime.utcnow().microsecond % 10000
    if ms != ms_:
        diff = (ms_ - ms) % 1000
        ms = ms_
        print ms, diff
```

It shows the change of microseconds (I'm just showing one more digit so the increase is visible):

```
8007 7    # garbage
8984 977
9960 976
937 977
1914 977
2890 976
3867 977
4843 976
5820 977
6796 976
7773 977
8750 977
9726 976
703 977
1679 976
2656 977
3632 976
4609 977
5585 976
```

As you can see, on my windows machine, the delta is quite consistent. It's just not 1000, like on the OP's machine, so that's why I (we?) observe different microseconds. The delta is probably in sync with some system clock, which, I guess, on the OP's machine retriggers in every milisecond?

Would love to hear some observations from others. Feel free to comment.

Note: this is a T4500, running at 2.30GHz.

Comment: Right now I'm considering clock speed... What's yours?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath You asked if we could replicate what you were seeing, and now, I can't. I always get diff=0 when I run your code: ``1286 0, 2286 0, 3286 0, 4286 0, etc...``

Comment: I get diff = 7 and 8 a lot on my machine

Comment: @dthor: you obviously can, and you do... the delta is the same, for you it's 1000.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Haha, yes, you're right. I wasn't thinking.