# Python 3 - Datetime.now() incorrect date

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
currentTime = datetime.now()
# Create file name for our picture
picTime = currentTime.strftime("%Y.%m.%d-%H%M%S")
```

Results are: 2018.04.29-03:43:52 while the correct time should be: 2018.04.28-22:43:52

Any thoughts on how to correct/troubleshoot this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python datetime.utcnow() returning incorrect datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28573873/python-datetime-utcnow-returning-incorrect-datetime)

Comment: Today is 2018.04.29... it looks correct to me :)

Comment: Your string format of %H%M%S doesn't contain a colon yet you claim the results do have a colon. Therefore, the results you show are not actually the result of `picTime`

Comment: @skam - while interesting, that question doesn't have an accepted answer so isn't a good candidate for duping. The problem there was a 1 hour difference, this one is likely just the difference between local and utc.

Comment: Why do you think its wrong? Does it not match your wall-clock time? What timezone are you in? Does `datetime.utcnow()` match current universal time (you could perhaps google "current utc time"`? Its possible that your system time is misconfigured.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The time is probably not configured correctly on your computer because it should work:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> currentTime = datetime.now()
>>> picTime = currentTime.strftime("%Y.%m.%d-%H%M%S")
>>> picTime
'2018.04.29-203446'
```

(it's my local time)

Comment: Maxime Cheramy thank you, the system on my device was incorrect set for the right localtime. 
Thank you for helping me troubleshoot the issue!

Answer (score 2):

It's possible you are in a virtualized environment (like docker) and your virtual timezone is different from the one in your host.

Your best shot would be to specify the timezone manually what's well described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).

Comment: Why would that work? If the system is misconfigured and giving the wrong time, this would give the wrong time also.

Comment: By that you can **manually** adjust the timezone - meaning a time shift from the currently presented time. This library allows adjusting your time shift with precision up to seconds. Who says you have to set it to your current timezone? OP just wants a right time.

Comment: ....so just hack the bug instead of figuring out the bug? Its just as easy to simply add or subtract a time delta to get the right time... for now. But the thing about masking bugs is they crop up again when the original conditions change.

Comment: My general thought was the OP might be in a virtual environment and may inspect if it doesn't require fixing on the system/environment level. But if the solution is needed fast, then a simple hack will be just in place.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you use time:

```
import time
time.time()
trime.ctime()
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: "Any thoughts on how to correct/troubleshoot this?"

Comment: sorry, I did not understand. Could you please give more details.