# Why is this simple pygame program lagging?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

So, I've been studying programming for a short time and decided to make the snake game in pygame. However, while making the base of the program I realized that the rectangle (snake) controlled by the player is teleporting (maybe by the lag) every second while moving. Here is the code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

# Window
window = (1280, 720)
center = (window[0]//2, window[1]//2)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(window)
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")

# Colors
COLOR_LIGHT_GREY = (200, 200, 200)
COLOR_DARK_GREY = pygame.Color('gray12')

# Game loop
game_loop = True
game_clock = pygame.time.Clock()


# Create image
def img(name):
    img_path = "./assets/natanael.lucena_" + name + ".png"
    return pygame.image.load(img_path).convert_alpha()


# Set object coordinates
def set_obj_coordinates(obj, x, y):
    obj.x = x
    obj.y = y


# Check player key press
def check_player_key(b):
    global snake_direction
    if event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s or event.key == pygame.K_a or event.key == pygame.K_d:
        snake_direction[event.key] = b


# Check key events in-game
def event_conditional():
    global game_loop
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        game_loop = False
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        check_player_key(True)
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        check_player_key(False)

# Check if the snake collided and the game is over
def game_over():
    if snake.y < 0 or snake.y > 720 or snake.x < 0 or snake. x > 1280:
        return True


# Snake
snake_img = img("snake")
snake = snake_img.get_rect()
move_keys = [pygame.K_w, pygame.K_d, pygame.K_s, pygame.K_a]
snake_direction = {k: False for k in move_keys}
snake_score = 0
snake_vel = 10
set_obj_coordinates(snake, center[0], center[1])


# Apple
apple_img = img("apple")
apple = apple_img.get_rect()
apple_eaten = False
set_obj_coordinates(apple, 40, 40)


# Main game loop
while game_loop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        event_conditional()
    # score_text = text_render(snake_score)
    if not game_over():
        for i in range(4):
            if i % 2:
                coord_aux = "x "
            else:
                coord_aux = "y "
            if i % 3:
                op = "+= "
            else:
                op = "-= "
            if snake_direction[move_keys[i]]:
                exec("snake." + coord_aux + op + "snake_vel")

        # the for loop above is equivalent to :
        # if snake_direction[move_keys[0]]:
        #    snake.y -= snake_vel
        # if snake_direction[move_keys[1]]:
        #    snake.x += snake_vel
        # if snake_direction[move_keys[2]]:
        #    snake.y += snake_vel
        # if snake_direction[move_keys[3]]:
        #    snake.x -= snake_vel

        screen.fill(COLOR_DARK_GREY)
        screen.blit(snake_img, snake)
        screen.blit(apple_img, apple)

    # Update screen
    pygame.display.flip()
    game_clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

[image: Here what's happening with me]
If someone can tell me the reason for the problem, I really appreciate it.

Edit: looks like the problem is just happening with me

Comment: You'd probably need to actually profile the code, but `exec` might be the culprit as it compiles that code every single cycle. Use something else, for example, `setattr`

Comment: *looks like the problem is just happening with me* Not at all. Just google something like 'pygame choppy movement' and you'll see this is a common problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats a common problem with pygame, especially since pygame 2/sdl 2 where you can't use the `directx` video driver and enable vsync anymore.

You should do the following:

- keep track of the sub-pixel coordinates of your moving game objects. A `Rect` can only store integer values in its `x` and `y`  attributes, so you'll need another variable to store this. I usually use a `Vector2` because it's easy to use and the performance hit usually does not matter anyway.
- use an accurate clock. Pygame's clock object only uses milliseconds, which is not accurate enough for really smooth movement. If you're on windows, usually the best method for timing is the `GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime` function.
- use a [delta timing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_timing).

You could also use different threads for the parts of your game that needs different timing methods (e.g. your game logic expects fixed 30 or 60 FPS and your drawing code wants to run as fast as possible), but that's overkill for your small game.

So here's an example I hacked together that gives you smooth movement (at least that's what I use usually since it works fine for me. Note that it's windows specific):

```
import pygame

import ctypes.wintypes

pygame.init()


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
center = screen.get_rect().center
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")


game_loop = True

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/28574340/142637
def utcnow_microseconds():
    system_time = ctypes.wintypes.FILETIME()
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime(ctypes.byref(system_time))
    large = (system_time.dwHighDateTime << 32) + system_time.dwLowDateTime
    return large // 10 - 11644473600000000

# Snake
snake_img = pygame.Surface((40, 40))
snake_img.fill('white')
snake = snake_img.get_rect()

snake_vel = 10
snake_pos = pygame.Vector2(center[0], center[1])
snake.topleft = snake_pos.x, snake_pos.y

# Apple
apple_img = pygame.Surface((40, 40))
apple_img.fill('red')
apple = apple_img.get_rect(topleft=(40, 40))


dt = 0
while game_loop:

    t1 = utcnow_microseconds()
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_loop = False
            
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    snake_pos.x += (keys[pygame.K_d] - keys[pygame.K_a]) * snake_vel * dt
    snake_pos.y += (keys[pygame.K_s] - keys[pygame.K_w]) * snake_vel * dt
    snake.topleft = snake_pos.x, snake_pos.y

    screen.fill('darkgrey')
    screen.blit(snake_img, snake)
    screen.blit(apple_img, apple)

    pygame.display.flip()

    t2 = utcnow_microseconds()
    dt = (t2 - t1) / 1000. / 1000. * 30

pygame.quit()
```

[Further reading](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/304).

Answer (score 1):

Very likely the bottleneck is the line

> ```py
> exec("snake." + coord_aux + op + "snake_vel")
> ```

`exec` has to parse and interpret the text in the argument.

This code can be easily improved

```py
if not game_over():
    for i in range(4):
        if snake_direction[move_keys[i]]:
            sign = 1 if i % 3 else -1
            if i % 2:
                snake.x += sign * snake_vel
            else:
                snake.y += sign * snake_vel
```

Since `snake` is a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object, you can even do the following:

```py
if not game_over():
    for i in range(4):
        if snake_direction[move_keys[i]]:
            sign = 1 if i % 3 else -1
            snake[(i+1) % 2] += sign * snake_vel
```

---

However:

The keyboard events (see [pygame.event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) module) occur only once when the state of a key changes. The `KEYDOWN` event occurs once every time a key is pressed. `KEYUP` occurs once every time a key is released. Use the keyboard events for a single action or a step-by-step movement.

[`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) returns a list with the state of each key. If a key is held down, the state for the key is `True`, otherwise `False`. Use [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed) to evaluate the current state of a button and get continuous movement.

Use `pygame.key.get_pressed()` for a smooth continuous movement:

```py
# Main game loop
while game_loop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        event_conditional()
    
    # score_text = text_render(snake_score)
    if not game_over():    
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        snake.x += (keys[pygame.K_d] - keys[pygame.K_a]) * snake_vel
        snake.y += (keys[pygame.K_s] - keys[pygame.K_w]) * snake_vel

        # [...]
```

Comment: thanks for the improvement tip, i replaced it, but the Rect is still teleporting by the lag every second somehow

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information in the question, i thought that this teleport thing was caused by lag but now i don't know the real reason of it. Maybe its just for me(?)

Comment: I edited the answer with a gif of what's happening to me. I also tried to restart my PC but the problem still there

Comment: Anyway, thanks for the help, i'll try to make another ask for this issue.