# Pygame inconsistent sprite speed

Tags: python, pygame

It could just be a product of lag, but in the Pygame import, my sprite movement is not consistent. At times it will be as expected, and then randomly speed up or jump across the screen.
I've tried both keypress loggers, the `.key_get_pressed()` and `event.type == KEYDOWN`, both have had the jumping issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A tale as old as time, see [Pygame Clock inaccurate](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/304) and related issues or [Why is this simple pygame program lagging?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66375253/142637)